# Как задать в запросе с where условие по дате?

Tags: python, база-данных, sql-server, pandas, csv

Я пишу запросы к БД SQL Server через pyodbc.

Если написать запрос таким образом, то столбец показывается:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Driver};'
                      'Server=сервер;'
                      'Database=БД;'
                      'username=логин;'
                      'password=пароль;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT дата FROM таблица ',conn)
print(sql_query)
sql_query.info()

Результат: дата
0   YYYY-MM-DD
1   YYYY-MM-DD
2   YYYY-MM-DD
3   YYYY-MM-DD
4   YYYY-MM-DD
..         ...
230 YYYY-MM-DD
231 YYYY-MM-DD
232 YYYY-MM-DD
233 YYYY-MM-DD
234 2020-07-20
```

Хочется написать запрос, который показывает только записи за дату 2020-07-20

Если написать так:

```
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT дата FROM таблица where дата = 2020-07-20 ',conn)
```

То выходит ответ: Empty DataFrame

```
Columns: дата
Index: []
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 0 entries
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   дата   0 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 0.0+ bytes
```

И пишет, что тип данных `object`.

Если написать так:

```
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT дата FROM таблица where дата = '2020-07-20' ',conn)
```

То выходит ошибка: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Пробовала написать запрос в самой БД. Там без кавычек так же пусто, а с кавычками такая ошибка:

> Преобразование типа данных varchar в тип данных datetime привело к выходу значения за пределы диапазона.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

наиболее идиоматичный способ - использование параметризованного запроса вместе со связанными переменными:

```
qry = """SELECT * FROM таблица WHERE дата = ?"""
params = [pd.to_datetime("2020-07-20")]
df = pd.read_sql(qry, conn, params=params)
```

вместо жесткого прописывания значений в запросе - лучше использовать параметризованные запросы (вместо значений используйте знак вопроса) и подставлять значения при помощи параметра `params`.

Обратите внимание на то, что мы используем для подстановки значение типа `datetime` и драйвер БД (`pyodbc`) сам позаботится о том как правильно подставить значение такого типа и нам не нужно задумываться о правильном квотировании литералов.

Кроме того, это будет эффективнее и безопаснее, т.к. сделает невозможным использование `SQL Injections`.

Comment: я запустила этот код, нет ошибок, но он ничего не выдал. что он делает?я запустила в общем вот так, params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=сервер;DATABASE=БД;UID=логин;PWD=пароль")
qry = """SELECT дата FROM таблица WHERE дата = ?"""
params = [pd.to_datetime("2020-07-20")]
df = pd.read_sql(qry, conn, params=params)

Comment: я добавила, print(df). напечатало столбик с данными. Вы можете пожалуйста объяснить, что делает данная часть кода. было бы неплохо, если бы печатало не только данные, но и все столбцы с такими датами